# How To create a Dependable Dropdown From Two Tables

Tags: php, mysql

[image: This is my first table]

[image: This is my second table]

I have two tables "**oc_t_item_car_make_attr**" , "**oc_t_item_car_model_attr**"

So how can i make a Dependable Dropdown From these Two Tables?

Comment: Could you please elaborate the words "Dependable Dropdown"?

Comment: When you select the first one from the list,then depend on that only you can select the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only do this by Ajax.

Following is city country reference site, you can get idea from that.

[Referance Site](http://phpseason.wordpress.com/2013/02/19/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using-jquery-and-ajax/)

if you stuck any where feel free to ask me.

Comment: here these are the three files [link]https://www.dropbox.com/sh/suo5hmbkoitn75q/02eY_l2nY2

Comment: sorry buddy i dont have access of dropbox in my office... i will look into this after office hours.. if its not urgent.

Answer (score 1):

Actually didn't understand question very well, but you probably want something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM oc_t_item_car_make_attr
INNER JOIN oc_t_item_car_model_attr
ON oc_t_item_car_model_attr.fk_i_make_id = oc_t_item_car_make_attr.pk_i_id
WHERE oc_t_item_car_make_attr.pk_i_id = ?
```

You need to insert id in the place of question mark.

Comment: actually i want to create something like this.. check this site.. the advance search on the right side [link]http://www.expatscarfinder.com/

Comment: Anyway, link does not help to understand your problem very well. You will probably need ajax, but don't get what you are asking about MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Hey you can do this by ajax

[Reference Link 1](http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/01/populate-triple-drop-down-list-change-options-value-from-database-using-ajax-and-php.html)

[Reference Link 2](http://buffernow.com/cascading-dropdown-ajax/)

also study inner join

Comment: While these links may answer the question, you should summarize or quote an article because links tend to decay over time.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the entire code what your looking for:

Below code will display all car names from database dynamically:

```
<select name="cars" id="carmodels">
<option value="">select</option>
<?php
$qry = mysqli_query("select * from oc_t_item_car_make_attr");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($qry)){
echo "<option value=".$row['pk_i_id'].">".$row['s_name']."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

Below result will display car models dependent on the names selected above:

html:

```
<select name="models" id="models">

</select>
```

you need to use ajax to get the car models from database:

```
$(document).on('change','#carmodels',function(){
var value = $(this).val();
$.ajax({
url: "demo.php",
type: "GET",
data: { id : value},
success: function(data){
$("#models").html(data);
}
});
```

**demo.php:**

```
<?php
include "connection.php";  //database connection code

$qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM oc_t_item_car_make_attr
INNER JOIN oc_t_item_car_model_attr
ON oc_t_item_car_model_attr.pk_i_id = oc_t_item_car_make_attr.pk_i_id
WHERE oc_t_item_car_make_attr.pk_i_id =".$_GET['id'].");
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($qry)){
echo "<option value=".$row['pk_i_id'].">".$row['s_name']."</option>";
}
?>
```